# Regex Pattern to Find and Replace

Tags: java, regex, replace

The Regex should identify texts like '0000046qwerty' and replace it with '46qwerty'.

Other Examples:

0000qw --> 0qw
123 --> 123
0123 --> 123
123qw --> 123qw
12003qw --> 12003qw

So, focus is mainly on the leading zeros and a way to truncate them in the appropriate scenario.

Solution I have is: (calls `replaceFirst` twice)

`text.replaceFirst("^[0]+(\\d+)", "$1").replaceFirst("^[0]*(\\d{1}\\w+)", "$1")`

Is there a single line regex to do the operation?

Comment: 0000qw --> 0qw seems not to be consistent with the other examples. Is there another rule that must hold?

Comment: @StefanA No. Nothing else I could identify from the data.

Comment: Don't you see that this rule does leave a `0` behind? Are not all zeros stripped - or is it a wrong example? Or is it a 'O'?

Comment: @StefanA : Yes, not all the zeros are stripped. It depends upon the successive value. If it is an alphabet then preserve a single zero else discard them.

Comment: so what was wrong with `text.replaceFirst("^[0]+(\\d+)", "$1")` without the second call to replaceFirst. The second call seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just "skip" leading zeros, leave one digit and any symbols after it:

```
text.replaceAll("^0+(\\d.*)", "$1")
```

Comment: Ya.. Didn't think like you did.. +1 :P

Comment: @StefanA - fixed. Add ^

Comment: But Neil was first ;)

Comment: Just still my idea and improve it :D

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is greedy so 0* will match as many zeroes as it can, leaving at least one digit to be matched with \d.  ^ means that only leading zeroes will be deleted.

```
text.replaceAll("^0*(\\d.*)", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex like this : This works for all your cases :P

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text="0000qw";
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("^0{2,}(?=0[^0])",""));
}
```

O/P :

```
0qw
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replaceFirst("^[0]+(\\d+)", "$1")
```

works with

```
0000qw -> 0qw

12003qw -> 12003qw
```

why do you call the second replaceFirst?